# UITextView: Much better performance after second scroll through

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a UITextView with a lot of text, and also images that I add with NSTextAttachment.

When scrolling through the text the first time, it's very laggy. However, when I reach the end, I can scroll through the whole text with no lagg.

I guess the images and text are lazily loaded when scrolling through the first time.

Is it possible to make it so it's always fast?

Thanks in advance